# Create a hollow arrow at the end of a PolylineConnection?

Tags: java, swt, draw2d

How can I create a hollow arrow at the end of a `PolylineConnection`?

Currently I have a solid arrow using:

```
PolylineConnection c
PolygonDecoration decoration = new PolygonDecoration();
PointList decorationPointList = new PointList();
decorationPointList.addPoint(0, 0);
decorationPointList.addPoint(-2, 2);
decorationPointList.addPoint(-2, 0);
decorationPointList.addPoint(-2, -2);
decoration.setTemplate(decorationPointList);
c.setSourceDecoration(decoration);
```

But I need only the outline of an arrow, with the center hollow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't have the time to test it, but [`setFill(boolean)`](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.draw2d.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/draw2d/Shape.html#setFill%28boolean%29) should do it:

```
decoration.setTemplate(decorationPointList);
decoration.setFill(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `drawPolyline`? It seems to after having a brief look at the docs that it should do what you are after.